# How to force a Kotlin sequence to a Kotlin sequence to evaluate

Tags: android, kotlin, view, sequence, viewgroup

How do you force a Kotlin [Sequence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj94qPotcjiAhUhTBUIHahTBUEQFjACegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkotlinlang.org%2Fapi%2Flatest%2Fjvm%2Fstdlib%2Fkotlin.sequences%2F-sequence.html&usg=AOvVaw1Ge2KDB3UJe0zjaxZZwSp8) to evaluate all pending operators? I know you can apply a terminal operation and I have achieved that by calling `.size` on the sequence but that feels like a hack and does not demonstrate intent. Is there a traditional way to evaluate a Sequence that demonstrates intent.

This is my intent, I am listing out all children of a view group and applying some operations on child items that match a predicate like this

```
viewGroup.children.filter{ it is FrameLayout }.map { child ->
             // Do something with child view 
               doSomeThingWithChildView()
            }
```

viewGroup.children returns a sequence but all the operators applied to it cannot be evaluated if a terminal operation is not called on the sequence. How do I force `doSomeThingWithChildView()` to be called?

Comment: Well, what is your intent? If your intent is too loop through the elements, you would use forEach. If your intent is to create a list with all the elements, you would use toList(). Just use the method that suits your needs.

Comment: I would update the question with my intent @JBNizet

Comment: Use forEach instead of map(). map() is used to transform a lazy sequence into another lazy sequence by transforming each element of the original one into something else. That's not what you want. You want to have trigger a side effect on each element of the sequence. That's what forEach() is for.

Comment: Don't you want to convert it to List? IMO, your approach with `size` is not really a hack, as Sequences are lazy by default. Lists are not however. Tldr: I'd go with `size` or `asList()`; don't see anything illegal with that. Anyway, usage of List is more suitable for your intent, I guess, due to your need of eager evaluation (instead of lazy)

Comment: @JBNizet I eventually used for each and it was cleaner, thanks.

Comment: @Maroš Šeleng asList() is a linear time computation, it goes through the sequence again and copies each value to the list.

Comment: @Ogbe I am familiar with what it does. My point was that the main goal of sequences is to be lazily evaluated when the value is needed (in comparison to eager list), thus I think, that you approach is fine. As is the approach with List.